# How to Install Apache Bigtop Stack with Ambari

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, bigdata, bigtop

Can any one provide tutorial or steps to installing  Apache BigTop stack using Ambari. I have tried using the repos provided in the below file

https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/src/main/resources/stacks/BIGTOP/0.8/repos/repoinfo.xml

However the bigtop stack not appearing the ambari dashboard UI.

I don't want to install using HDP stack.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.8.0).

That link included `Installation Guide for Ambari 2.8.0` and `Build Bigtop components`